# How do i store the user's answer in an array so that it can check with the correct ans

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function

This is how the quiz should work: 
When the user type in the ans, it should store the ans in an array so that it can check with the correct ans in another array.

```
var input = require("read_line-sync");
class Multiple_choice {
    constructor(number,question,choices,user_ans,correct_ans) {
        this.number = number; //question number
        this.question = question; //display question number
        this.choices = choices; //display question choices
        this.user_ans = user_ans; // store user ans
        this.correct_ans = correct_ans; // validate user ans
    }
}

class Quiz{
    quiz(category){// to store objects in different categories
        if (category==1){
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
                console.log(questions[i].number + questions[i].question + questions[i].choices + ???); // questions 1-5:History
            }

        }
        else if (category==2){
            for(var i=5;i<10;i++){
                console.log(questions[i].number + questions[i].question + questions[i].choices + ???); // questions 6-10: Chemistry
            }
        }
        else if (category==3){
            for(var i=10;i<15;i++){
                console.log(questions[i].number + questions[i].question + questions[i].choices +???); // question 11-15: Physics
            }
        }
    }
var questions =[new Multiple_Choice("Question 1: \n","There was an early settlement long before the arrival of Stamford Raffles. It was located between the mouth of the Singapore River and a small watercourse known today as Stamford Canal. What was the original name of this stream?","A. Fresh Water Well\n B. Fresh Water Lake\n C. Fish Water Spring\n D. Fresh Water Spring",user_ans,correct_ans),
                new Multiple_Choice("Question 2: \n","When did the first junk transporting immigrants from China arrive in Singapore?","1820\n 1821\n 1822\n 1823",user_ans,correct_ans),
                new Multiple_Choice("Question 3: \n","The earliest mosque in Singapore is believed to be","A. Jamar mosque\n B. Omar mosque \n C. Al Abram mosque \n D. Hajj ah Fatima mosque",user_ans,correct_ans)
                new Multiple_Choice("Question 4: \n","The oldest Jewish synagogue is the Mag both built in 1878. It is located at","\n A. Queen Street\n B. Waterloo Street \n C. Victoria Street\n D. cool Street",user_ans,correct_ans),
                new Multiple_Choice("Question 5: \n","The Sikhs make up a small but significant proportion of the Indian population of Singapore. They began arriving in Singapore from as early as 1881. Committed to their religion, they set about establishing temples. Today, the Central Sikh Temple is an imposing building, capped by an impressive dome. Where is it located?","\n A. Queen Street\n B. Silas Street\n C. Town Road \n D. mayflower Road",user_ans,correct_ans),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice(),
                new Multiple_Choice()];
var name = new Quiz();
name.quiz();
```

i did not include all the questions so the code will not be very lengthy.
Question 1-5 is an example.

??? stands for obtaining user input after reading the question

Comment: You can concatenate question properties as a string: `console.log( question[i].number + ' - ' + question[i].question + ' - ' + ...) `

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tip. Rather than creating objects for each question explicitly, use an efficient data structure to do the same. Since you are using Node.js, you can try out file based storage using the 'fs' module. Store your questions as an array of objects. I would suggest the following schema for each question object:

```
category: STRING,
question: STRING,
correctAnswers: [CORRECT ANSWER IDS],
options: [{
    id: INTEGER,
    statement: STRING,
    isCorrect: Boolean
}]
```

Comment: sry i am new to programming so i not quite understand what you mean. Can explain it in a more detailed manner? How does that work in the array?

Comment: Not a problem. Similar to an array of integers, you can loop over an array of objects. Here's an example:  var array = [{ name: 'Han', age: 20  }, { name: 'Rohit', age: 22 } ]. When you loop over this array, you can interact with an individual object.  Using this concept, you can store your questions along with answers in an array, each single object can contain your questions and an array of options. Yes, array inside objects. I would suggest you to work with some public apis to get a hold of JSON and how it works.

Comment: can show me an example how to do it with this question? i have made some edits.

Comment: Do some research about the fs module in node.js. Learn about how arrays and objects work together. Learn about JSON and how to handle a json response.  There are some excellent tutorials out there, learn about the core concepts and come back to the quiz application.

Comment: Also, learn about available Array methods to make your life easier.

Comment: okay thanks for your help i will learn that before getting back to this question

Comment: Is it possible to send me some relevant links to learn what you mention?

Comment: Just google. Learn about core concepts javascript before moving on to node.js, that always helps. There are some excellent courses out there. [this](https://codeburst.io/javascript-understanding-the-weird-parts-d1d0e7061ebf) is my favourite.